# Retrieving roles of a user in an Azure AD when federating to the AD from an Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, claims-based-identity, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I have both Azure AD and Azure AD B2C directories. I have setup custom policies per [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom)  and able to federate to Azure AD from Azure AD B2C for authentication. I would like to control access by the roles the users have in the Azure AD. However, I am not sure how to accomplish this? 
At the end of the flow, the claims I get back only have basic user info, and no role data. What do I need to do to have the claims include the user's roles in Azure AD? If that's not possible, what would be a recommended way to achieve this goal? I was thinking another way is to use Microsoft Graph. That would entail I need to know the object id of the user and the id of the Azure AD tenant. However, In the token, I only get back basic user info and the object id of the user is different than the actual id in Azure AD.

Appreciate any help regarding this.